# Collective member page is broken (Go Collective)

Tags: bug, status-planned, collectives

The member page of the Go Collective is broken: https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/go?tab=members

I suspect this is because a user who was recently deleted was also in the top-3 leaderboard — their user card used to show up with the gold trophy icon of the Collective.

Now that the profile is gone, the backend is probably having issues rendering the page.

Just to state the obvious: the member pages of other Collectives work just fine. I believe the circumstances leading to this bug, if my guess is correct, are rather hard to replicate. Regardless, it looks like a bug.

This is what the page looks like right now:

[image]

Comment: I don't know if this has been fixed or not since the tag still says [tag:status-planned], but I could open the page now.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! We've indeed "fixed" the issue, but couldn't find the root cause of it, we'll be looking into this further and will update this question whenever we've figured it out and fixed it "for good"

Comment: @JD-Stack thanks, so you can confirm that the cause was *not* a leaderboard top-3 user being deleted?

Comment: @blackgreen ultimately, the cause was a null reference error when pulling data out of our cache.  Unfortunately, the stack traces were pointing to an unuseful location, so we're not positive as to the source of the null value.  Clearing and rebuilding the cache "fixed" the issue, but we're still investigating the source of the null.  It very well could have been due to the deleted user, just not in an obvious way.